# cannot connect to pi via sftp filezilla on mac but ssh via terminal successful

Tags: ssh, remote, data-transfer

I am fairly new to command line and rPi, all previous experience has been desktop & web apps and have fallen at a major hurdle with my new Pi.

As the title suggests I am struggling to sftp into the rpi with the final intention of controlling GPIO via a web app. most importantly I can log into the pi successfully using SSH terminal for mac.

1. Pi is connected to router via ethernet and I am running my laptop
   over wifi
2. Pi has a static IP, this has been confirmed over router.
3. Not sure if it was necessary at this stage but port forwarding has
   been setup on router.
4. Ran pi updates/upgrades
5. I have changed my password
6. PasswordAuthentication yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
7. connection via cyber duck gives this error: Interoperability
   failure: EOF while reading packet. Please contact your web hosting
   service provider for assistance.
8. connection via filezilla gives me this error after previously saying
   connected: Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server.
9. SFTP connection via terminal: asks me for my password then instantly says
   connection closed.
10. Disabling router firewall made no difference so i reenabled.
11. I was following this tutorial if that helps: [tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-and-intuitive-web-interface-for-your-Raspbe/)

I have spent the most part of today searching the internet and so far no solutions have fixed my problem.

Being new to command line I am struggling to really delve into the debugging stage and not totally sure what I should be looking for.

edit: I have ran the sftp in terminal with -v

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.0.42 ([192.168.0.42]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2032, received 1680 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 165392.2, received 136741.6
debug1: Exit status 127
Connection closed
```

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/sftp-connection-error-received-unexpected-end-of-file-from-sftp-server seems to describe the same problem and offers some potential fixes / workarounds. BTW: I don't have any problems with filezilla / sftp on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Dirk for pointing me in the right direction! For anyone else with this problem it was fixed by editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Commenting out the line

```
# Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

And adding the line

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

I then power cycled the pi for good measure and voila!